# Does the entropy of a system of two gravitating bodies increase as they get closer together?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

It seems like the situation where the two gravitating bodies have collided and coalesced (assuming that they don’t shatter on impact) can be thought of as the ‘equilibrium’ of the system, since this is the ‘natural’ state that  the system tends to. I think it is also correct to say that the free energy of the system will be large when the bodies are far apart and small when they are stuck together. This is because we could harness work from the bodies as they are accelerating towards each other, but could not extract any more work once they have coalesced. Both of these observations would suggest to me naively that the entropy of the two-body system has increased during the process where the two bodies collide and coalesce.

However, I am trying to understand this in terms of the Gibbs entropy $$S_G = -k \int\rho(r)\log(\rho(r))\mathrm dr,$$ where $\rho(r)$ is the probability density function and $r$ is a vector of phase space coordinates. Where does the gravitational potential between the bodies come into the expression for the Gibbs entropy? I think that my problem may partly (or wholly) come from the fact that I do not understand the link between the Gibbs entropy and the thermodynamic entropy $\mathrm dS = \mathrm dQ/T$, though my understanding is that Jaynes showed that they were equivalent.

I suppose that my question is less to do with gravity and more to do with the relationship between potentials and entropy. I would be equally happy with an answer to the question 'Does the entropy of two bodies in a repulsive potential increase as they get further apart?'

Many thanks.

Comment: I am not sure entropy is really to be considered for a system of just two bodies

Comment: If we take [*tidal forces*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_force) into account, then most likely  increase

Answer (score 2):

Entropy is a physical property (state property) of the materials comprising the bodies, and this doesn't change until they have collided and coalesced.  Each body has its own entropy prior to the collision and coalescence, and, afterwards, the final entropy of the combination is higher than the sum of the entropies prior to collision.  This is because the kinetic energy of the bodies just before collision is converted into internal energy as a result of  the collision, so the temperatures of the bodies is higher (assuming they were equal before the collision).  If the bodies were at different temperatures before the collision, the entropy increase will be even greater.

Answer (score 0):

Aaron Stevens is right, but maybe one way to think of it is to start by considering space as a series of boxes, and your two bodies occupy one box each. The entropy is related to the number of states that the system can occupy. This means all possible ways of putting $2$ balls in $N$ boxes (then take $N$ to infinity if you like). The entropy does not relate to how close they are, but how many different ways they can be rearranged in the space you give them. Once they coalesce, however, the number of accessible states changes, and hence the entropy will change.

So to answer your question - I would say no, the entropy would not change.